# Android: Open Sliding Drawer in Graphical Layout in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml

Is it possible to open a `SlidingDrawer` when viewed inside the Eclipse graphical layout preview? By default it's closed when viewed so I cannot see what is happening with the layouts inside the `SlidingDrawer`.

If this isn't possible, what would be the best way to handle this problem? A separate layout file I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a standard way to do this.

I currently use the following method: override SlidingDrawer.onFinishInflate() to force it open when in Eclipse layout preview.

import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;

```
public class MySlidingDrawer extends SlidingDrawer {

    public MySlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MySlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            open();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, of course, replace SlidingDrawer by my.package.MySlidingDrawer in layout.xml.